# Selenium in python - Browser closing immediately after open testprogamm

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

As soon as I run my program, google opens (so far so good) but this window closes immediately after the program has run. I already installed the chromdriver (also matches the version of the search engine) and put it in the script folder in Python. Can someone help me?

Here is my Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://google.com")
```

Comment: Is this the full code?

Comment: @Sushil yess, thats my full code. Just wanted to see if I can start a website with this code. But it doesn't work

Comment: Plus, one mistake that I noticed is that the url of google is incorrect. It should be ```https://www.google.com/``` rather than ```http://www.google.com/``` IDK if this is the problem, but this is a mistake that I noticed in ur code.

Comment: No, opens up the website and close it immediately. Same probem again.

Comment: Ok, i will try.

Comment: Just tried to restart my computer, but it still won't work :( I'm sitting here for 3 hours and still haven't found the problem.

Comment: :( Recheck whether ur chromedriver matches ur chrome version.

Comment: I have deleted the old one and installed the new one just to check i use the right version. But it still crashes :( I don't know what to do anymore

Comment: Oh :( I really don't know what the problem is. I don't think that I can help u anymore. Sry. Maybe one thing that u can do is download geckodriver and run the same code using it.

Comment: Ok I will try. Thank you for your help

Comment: In order to use geckodriver, replace ```webdriver.Chrome()``` with ```webdriver.Firefox()```.

Comment: Tried it. Still doesn't work. I don't know what to do anymore. Anyways, thank you for your help!

Comment: Oh.....So sad :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google chrome closes immediately after being launched with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47508518/google-chrome-closes-immediately-after-being-launched-with-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an excecutable path for a chrome driver to be able to open a browser.
download a driver based on your browser in your case it's Chrome from here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

then driver = webdriver.Chrome(here you have to write the path of the driver),you can put it wherever you want.