# permission issue while i am opening chrome webdriver into function in python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am opening chrome webdriver in python.It is working fine when i am not opening via function.With function is say some permission issue and i have administration access :-

```
url=['https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=free+code+camp']

def main1():

    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
        driver.get(url[0])
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
main1()
```

Without function is it working. Webdriver open and after few second i got this issue :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\Jinja2_sample1\lib\subprocess.py", line 788, in __del__
    self._internal_poll(_deadstate=_maxsize)
  File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\envs\Jinja2_sample1\lib\subprocess.py", line 1055, in _internal_poll
    if _WaitForSingleObject(self._handle, 0) == _WAIT_OBJECT_0:
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

Comment: Is `chromedriver.exe` on your path?

Comment: Yes. it is running without using function

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) library. It simplifies the work with drivers.

*Here is the code that worked for me:*

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

url=['https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=free+code+camp']

def main1():

    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
        driver.get(url[0])
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

main1()
```

Also I used venv, not Anaconda

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your code is running without the function, the issue might be caused by the garbage collector.

As per this discussion [Google chrome closes immediately after being launched with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47508518/google-chrome-closes-immediately-after-being-launched-with-selenium).

To prevent this, we can return the driver object from the function

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver


url = ['https://stackoverflow.com']
def main1():
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
        driver.get(url[0])
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    return driver

driver = main1()
time.sleep(1)
driver.quit()
```

Try updating your selenium version, it seems to work for v 3.141.0 in conda